# Rails Cloud Server - Installed NGINX but rails app still uses WEBrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, passenger, digital-ocean

So I've bought and set up my DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 Droplet, set up SSH keys, bought a domain name, transfered my app to the DigitalOcean cloud server using Filezilla and install Passenger with NGINX. It took a lot of trial, error and research but I've learned a lot from it.

The problem is, I still can't get the it to work! When I start my $rails s -e production in the cloud, I noticed it still uses Webrick despite already installing NGINX. I also get a 500 Internal Service Error from NGINX when I visit my website's IP address.

Its likely that I did something wrong, but due to my inexperience, I have no way of really knowing what procedure was incorrect/skipped. Maybe something with Capistrano? my secret keys still need some work done, not sure :/

Can someone help me out?

---

My checklist:

1. Install Ruby and Rails and bundle install in my Cloud Server [done]
2. Install NGINX and Passenger following the tutorial at: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04 [done]
3. Edited my NGINX config file to:

   server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name 45.55.136.43;
   passenger_enabled on;
   passenger_app_env production;
   root /origins/public;
   }

Comment: You don't transfer a Rails app to a production server using a FTP client. Use something like capistrano to deploy your app to a production server.

Comment: wow this is news to me... haha ok so I use capistrano. So do I use capistrano first, and then install nginx/passenger? or do they accomplish the same thing?

Comment: You configure nginx first. Read more here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-automate-ruby-on-rails-application-deployments-using-capistrano